# how to search for a particular string from a .gz file?

Tags: linux, grep, gzip

I want to search for a particular string from a .gz file containing a text file without extracting in linux terminal. I know how to search for a string from a text file using `grep "text to search" ./myfile.txt`. But how to make it work for .gz files?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```bash
gunzip -c mygzfile.gz | grep "string to be searched"
```

But this would only work if the .gz file contains text file which is true in your case.

Answer (score 63):

You can use [`zgrep`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zgrep.htm). Usage is similar to `grep`.

```bash
zgrep "pattern" file.gz
```

From the `man` page's description:

> Zgrep invokes grep on compressed or gzipped files. All options
> specified are passed directly to grep. If no file is specified, then
> the standard input is decompressed if necessary and fed to grep.
> Otherwise the given files are uncompressed if necessary and fed to
> grep.

Comment: you can do wildcard for all gz file in folder ```zgrep "pattern" *.gz```

Comment: `zgrep` does not support recursive search. Should you need to search recursively, use `find . -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep "pattern" {} \;` And make sure to escape characters that might form a regular expressions in your pattern.

Answer (score 6):

Already it have been answered, but it could be really helpful if you want to search in multiple .gz files.

For searching in all the .gz files in a specific folder you can use

```bash
zgrep "yourString" *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zcat

zcat ./myfile.txt | grep "text to search"