# How to read data in .gz file very fast in perl programming

Tags: perl

I am reading a .gz file which is around 3 GB. I am grepping a pattern using Perl program. I am able to grep the pattern but it is taking too long to process. Can anyone help me how to process very fast?

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Compress::Zlib;
my $file = "test.gz";
my $gz = gzopen ($file, "rb") or die "Error Reading $file: $gzerrno";
while ($gz->gzreadline($_) > 0 ) {
if (/pattern/) {
print "$_----->PASS\n";
}
}
die "Error reading $file: $gzerrno" if $gzerrno != Z_STREAM_END;
$gz ->gzclose();
```

What does `Z_STREAM_END` variable do?

Comment: Have you tried just using `zgrep`? See relevant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24218049/3558960).

Comment: Sorry Robby, I was creating a script for automatically process few file for data manipulation. One of the task to process a .gz file. so I cant use grep command here.

Comment: No, but at least you could compare speeds, and based on that determine whether your perl file reading can be optimized further.

Comment: Another thought: the pattern itself might also be simplified to be a little more gentle on the regex engine.

Comment: Thanks I can give a try but is there any other options I could try

Comment: None that I can see immediately, but it's been a decade since I did any serious perl :)

Comment: Do you need to continue reading once the pattern has been found?

Comment: Before `while` loop declare `my $precompiled_re = qr/pattern/;`  and later in `if` just use `if ($precompiled_re)`. Please check. Regex are costly and precompiling boosts the speed specially when you are using in loop in 3 GB file.

Comment: @choroba Yes I need to read

Comment: for one file it takes nearly 1 min. But I need to process this for around 25 files.

Comment: @varunkumar did you try precompiling the regex user `qr` as I mentioned above. Please try.

Answer (score 6):

I have written a script that times how long various methods take to read a gz file.  I too have also found that `Compress::Zlib` is very slow.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie ':all';
use Compress::Zlib;
use Time::HiRes 'time';

my $file = '/home/con/Documents/snp150.txt.gz';
# time zcat execution
my $start_zcat = Time::HiRes::time();
open my $zcat, "zcat $file |";
while (<$zcat>) {
  #      print $_;
}
close $zcat;
my $end_zcat = Time::HiRes::time();
# time Compress::Zlib reading
my $start_zlib = Time::HiRes::time();
my $gz = gzopen($file, 'r') or die "Error reading $file: $gzerrno";
while ($gz->gzreadline($_) > 0) {#http://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-read-and-write-compressed-files-in-perl
#       print "$_";# Process the line read in $_
}
$gz->gzclose();
my $end_zlib = Time::HiRes::time();

printf("zlib took %lf seconds.\n", $end_zlib - $start_zlib);
printf("zcat took %lf seconds.\n", $end_zcat - $start_zcat);
```

Using this script, I found that reading through `zcat` runs about 7x faster (!) than `Compress::Zlib`  This will vary from computer to computer, and file to file, of course.

Comment: Is there any difference running on a single core computer vs multi?

Comment: @Shawn I don't know