# Reading gzip line from line on a mac

Tags: macos, perl

I have a gargantuan .gz file that I can read on Perl/Linux via

```
open my $zc, 'zcat GCF_000001405.25.gz|';
```

but when I run this code on a Mac (Perl 5.32.1) I get an error:

```
zcat: can't stat: GCF_000001405.25.gz (GCF_000001405.25.gz.Z): No such file or directory
```

so following https://serverfault.com/questions/570024/zcat-gzcat-works-in-linux-not-on-osx-general-linux-osx-compatibility

I tried

```
open my $zc, 'zcat < GCF_000001405.25.gz';
```

but this gives the error:

```
readline() on closed filehandle $zc at split.by.chr.pl line 32
```

I am aware of `Compress::Zlib` but it is very slow [How to read data in .gz file very fast in perl programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899310/how-to-read-data-in-gz-file-very-fast-in-perl-programming/59900780#59900780)

How can I change the `open` line in my perl script so that it will work on a Mac?

Comment: You should add `or die $!` at the end of the `open` line. When doing `open my $zc, 'zcat < GCF_000001405.25.gz';`: it would say _No such file or directory..._, which should help finding the issue.

Comment: @Dada thanks, I normally use `use autodie ':default'` at the start of every script

Comment: Good idea. Although in this case you forgot it, since otherwise you would have had a more useful error.

Comment: Why describe your file as *"gargantuan"*? If it's 700MB that's fine, just say - that's perfectly clear and more helpful. Is its size even relevant to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attempt on the OP leaves out the `|` that indicates the string is a program to run and not a file name. As such, the correct answer is to use

```
open my $zc, 'zcat < GCF_000001405.25.gz|';
```

See https://alvinalexander.com/perl/edu/articles/pl010004.shtml